# Initialization commands cannot be evaluated

Tags: matlab, simulink

I took the 'Performance of Three PSS for Interarea Oscillations' simulink model. I have disabled the link for 'Delta w PSS' block and modified (removed some connections and added new blocks) it according to my usage. Now when I simulate I am getting an error "Initialization commands cannot be evaluated" on this 'Delta w PSS'block.
What should I do to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it cannot initialize some of the mask parameters. If you right-click on the block and choose "View Mask...", you'll see what the initialization commands are under the "Initialization" block (you may have to go back to the library block). Unfortunately, once you start breaking/disabling library links and modifying library blocks, you're on your own...

Answer (score 0):

In Power electronics, I saw this error and I have added a block named powergui and it solved. to find it I searched `powergui` 
it may help you to find such this block in your kind of use